# change button font from within custom button class, android

Tags: android, button, fonts

I am making custom buttons for my app and want to set the font they are using within the custom button class (extending Button).  I can set the font from the main class with the following code:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Korean_Calligraphy.ttf");
custom_button.setTypeface(font);
```

which works fine, but I have multiple buttons to apply this too and for the sake of tidy and succinct code, would rather everything was handled inside the button class itself.  So two questions:

- How do I access the TextView of the Button from within my custom button class?
- How do I reference the font file as it seems to not let me use getAssets() within the button class?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I access the TextView of the Button from within my custom button class

`Button` *IS A* `TextView` so you don't need to do anything special here. Just work with a button like with a regular text view.

> How do I reference the font file as it seems to not let me use getAssets() within the button class?

Obtain a `Context` instance and use its `getAssets()`:

```
Context context = getContext();
context.getAssets()... //do anything you need
```

Comment: that simple hey?  thanks for the help - worked great :)  one more question.  i am setting my BackgroundDrawables and font in the onDraw method of my custom button and i see the default art and font for a split second before my custom stuff pops in.  any way to avoid that happening?

Comment: @Emma Assin Heh doing that in onDraw() doesn't sound performant. You have to do that only once in a constructor of your view.

Comment: thanks, yeah i moved it to the constructor already, but still get the brief flash of the default art before my art loads in.  any idea how to get rid of that?

Comment: @Emma Assin.. hmm that's really weird, are you sure you're not doing anything in onDraw?

Comment: *embarrassment* i had moved the font code but left the drawables code in onDraw!  whoops.  it's working now, thanks! :)